# How to group factor levels?

Tags: r

I have a factor column with football position abbreviations, around 17 unique values with 220 observations. I want to have only three factor levels which encompass the 17 unique values.

```
levels(nfldraft$Pos) <- list(Linemen = c("C","OG","OT","TE","DT","DE"),
                             Small_Backs =  c("CB","WR","FS"), 
                             Big_Backs = c("FB","ILB","OLB","P","QB",
                                           "RB","SS","WR"))
```

is what I tried, printing `nfldraft$Pos` to the console shows 3 factor levels but all the values are either `"Linemen"` or `"Small_Backs"` and all the other ones are `NA`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please show a reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Factor levels can only be a vector of one tier, not a list.

Comment: WR is in two categories.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's hard to say what went wrong, but 42's guess is a good one. @alistaire, factor levels can be reassigned using a list. In fact, it can be rather efficient. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1104/factors/6565/consolidating-factor-levels-with-a-list#t=201608132159126191797

Comment: @alistaire see `?levels`. `levels` can can only be a vector, but `levels<-` accepts a `list` on the RHS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made up an example character vector with all of the abbreviations:

```
my_example <- c("C","OG","OT","TE","DT","DE","CB","WR","FS", 
                "FB","ILB","OLB","P","QB","RB","SS","WR")
class(my_example)
```

> [1] "character"

Then I substituted the desired levels for their abbreviations (you could also use `gsub` here or any of many, many different approaches):

```
my_example[my_example %in% c("C","OG","OT","TE","DT","DE")] <- "Linemen"
my_example[my_example %in% c("CB","WR","FS")]               <- "Small Backs"
my_example[my_example %in% c("FB","ILB","OLB","P",
                             "QB","RB","SS","WR")]          <- "Big Backs"
```

Then I made it into a factor:

```
my_example <- as.factor(my_example)
head(my_example)
```

> ```
> [1] Linemen Linemen Linemen Linemen Linemen Linemen
> Levels: Big Backs Linemen Small Backs
> ```

```
tail(my_example)
```

> ```
> [1] Big Backs   Big Backs   Big Backs   Big Backs   Big Backs   Small Backs
> Levels: Big Backs Linemen Small Backs
> ```

```
class(my_example)
```

> [1] "factor"

Comment: Might be safer to assign to s different name, since the targe item might be a factor in a dataframe.

Comment: I did this: `> nfldraft$Pos[nfldraft$Pos %in% c("C","OG","OT","TE","DT","DE")] <- "Linemen"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, nfldraft$Pos %in% c("C", "OG", "OT", "TE",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`

Comment: @AminSammara That's because you didn't start with a character vector. So, do `nfldraft$Pos <- as.character(nfldraft$Pos)` first and you'll be good

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of needing a fully reproducible example. Actually OP's code *looks* like it should work. Taking from @Hack-R's sample input:

```
my_example <- c("C","OG","OT","TE","DT","DE","CB","WR","FS", 
                "FB","ILB","OLB","P","QB","RB","SS","WR")
```

OP's original code works as-is:

```
nfldraft = list(Pos = factor(my_example))
levels(nfldraft$Pos) <- list(
  Linemen = c("C","OG","OT","TE","DT","DE"), 
  Small_Backs =  c("CB","WR","FS"), 
  Big_Backs = c("FB","ILB","OLB","P","QB","RB","SS","WR")
)
table(nfldraft$Pos)
#     Linemen Small_Backs   Big_Backs 
#           6           2           9
```

This is exactly in line with the documentation for how to use `levels<-`:

> `levels(x) <- value`
>
> `value` A valid value for `levels(x)`... For the factor method, a vector of character strings with length at least the number of levels of x, **or a named list specifying how to rename the levels**.

So it seems there's something else wrong with OP's input

Comment: That this now works might be due to a change in `factor()` in `R 3.5.0`, see "CHANGES IN R 3.5.0" in [release notes](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/NEWS.3). But you are absolutely right with the reproducible example!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the *mapvalues()* function from dplyr package.

In your example it would be:

```
Linemen_levels = c("C","OG","OT","TE","DT","DE")
Small_Backs_levels = c("CB","WR","FS")
Big_Backs_levels = c("FB","ILB","OLB","P","QB","RB","SS","WR")

nfldraft <- nfldraft %>% mutate(Pos=mapvalues(Pos, 
                 from = c(Linemen_levels, Small_Backs_levels, Big_Backs_levels),
                 to = c(rep('Linemen', length(Linemen_levels), rep('Small_Backs', length(Small_Backs_levels), rep('Big_Backs', length(Big_Backs_levels))))))
```