# How do you group factor levels in R?

Tags: r

I have a column in my dataset with likert scale responses that range from Very Likely to Not Likely. I would like to bind a new column that has grouped several of the factor levels. For example, the new column would have only two factor levels: one that consists of Very Likely, Likely and another column with Slightly Likely and Not Likely. I was planning on turning the new column into a numeric and computing some statistical tests. I am hoping to do something like this in the end:

```
Grouped_Levels <- as.numeric(Grouped_Levels)
mydata <- cbind(mydata, Grouped_Levels) 

Statistical_Testing.aov <- aov(Grouped_Levels ~ Question, data = mydata)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group factor levels in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934943/how-to-group-factor-levels-in-r)

Comment: @mnm That may be true, but it is an old question and therefore perhaps confusing, because the failing method actually works.

Comment: @jay.sf I don't see the significance of labeling a given Q as old or new, especially when the earlier Q and this current Q in context are syntactically the same. Moreover, which `failing method` are you referring too?

Comment: @mnm "old" is appropriate, because the problem of your linked question can probably no longer be reproduced with newer R versions, see newer answer to this question with my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60316880/6574038

Comment: @jay.sf I see your point in the comment that you just posted on the linked Q. Should I then not perceive it (read your comment on the linked Q) as a forced justification to supplement your answer here, as well as negation to accept that this Q was indeed duplicate. My point here is, your comment on the linked Q was posted 2 hours ago. And I see it as concoction of your response in this Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping factor levels can easily be done by assigning the grouping in a list. Here an example with toy data:

```
levels(mydata$value)
# [1] "not likely"      "slightly likely" "likely"          "very likely"    

levels(mydata$value) <- list("unlikely"=c("not likely", "slightly likely"),
                           "likely"=c("likely", "very likely"))
levels(mydata$value)
# [1] "unlikely" "likely"
```

After that you probably want to do this:

```
(Statistical_Testing.aov <- aov(as.integer(value) ~ question, data = mydata))
# Call:
#   aov(formula = as.integer(value) ~ question, data = mydata)
# 
# Terms:
#   question Residuals
# Sum of Squares      0.18      5.82
# Deg. of Freedom        1        23
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.5030343
# Estimated effects may be unbalanced

(Statistical_Testing.anova <- anova(Statistical_Testing.aov))
# Analysis of Variance Table
# 
# Response: as.integer(value)
#           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
# question   1   0.18 0.18000  0.7113 0.4077
# Residuals 23   5.82 0.25304
```

---

*Toy data:*

```
set.seed(42)
mydata <- transform(expand.grid(question=1:5, id=1:5),
                    value=factor(sample(1:4, 25, rep=T), 
                                 labels=c("not likely", "slightly likely", 
                                          "likely", "very likely")))
```