# How do I group different elements of a csv file into the same group?

Tags: r

I'm making a grouped bar plot. Here is my code:

```
imagedata <- read.csv(file = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\firstactivity\\data\\synthea_sample_data_csv_apr2020\\csv\\imaging_studies.csv")
bodysite <- imagedata$BODYSITE_DESCRIPTION
mod <- imagedata$MODALITY_CODE
bodysite_case <- tolower(bodysite) #so that "thoracic" and "Thoracic" will be categorized together
barplot(table(mod, bodysite_case), main = "Imaging Studies", ylab = "Frequency", names.arg=c("Ankle","Arm","Chest","Clavicle","Knee","Pelvis","RUQ","Thoracic","Thoracic structure","Thoracic body structure","Wrist"),col = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow"), legend.text = colnames(table),las=2, beside=TRUE)
title(xlab = "Body Site", line = 4, adj=0)
legend("top", fill=c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow"), c("CR", "CT", "DX", "US"))
```

And here is my current produced bar plot:
[image: current bar plot]

How do I make it so that I can combine the thoracic groups (which are the 8th, 9th and 10th categories from left to right) into one group, since they have very similar names?

Here's my data sample with dput:

```
structure(c(0L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 48L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 31L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 172L, 0L, 0L, 61L, 0L, 76L, 328L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 47L, 0L), .Dim = c(4L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(mod = c("CR", 
"CT", "DX", "US"), bodysite_case = c("ankle", "arm", "chest", 
"clavicle", "knee", "pelvis", "structure of right upper quadrant of abdomen", 
"thoracic", "thoracic structure", "thoracic structure (body structure)", 
"wrist")), class = "table")
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data with `dput()`

Comment: Added the result of dput(). Is this what you meant?

Comment: You're probably better off fixing the issue in `imagedata` rather than after making the table. Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934943/how-to-group-factor-levels for grouping the thoracic categories. But you can group it up afterwards if you like: `barplot(cbind(dat[,-(8:10)], thoracic=rowSums(dat[,8:10] )), beside=TRUE)` as a quick fix.

Answer (score 2):

## Data

```
    df <-
  structure(c(0L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 48L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 
              0L, 0L, 31L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
              1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 172L, 0L, 0L, 61L, 0L, 76L, 328L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
              0L, 47L, 0L),
            .Dim = c(4L, 11L),
            .Dimnames = list(mod = c("CR", 
                                     "CT", "DX", "US"),
                             bodysite_case = c("ankle", "arm", "chest", 
                                               "clavicle", "knee", "pelvis", "structure of right upper quadrant of abdomen", 
                                               "thoracic", "thoracic structure", "thoracic structure (body structure)", 
                                               "wrist")), class = "table")
```

## A tidyverse solution

```
df %>% 
  #Transform data format from table to a data.frame
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  #Unite levels with thoracic detected in the string
  mutate(
    bodysite_case = as.character(bodysite_case),
    bodysite_case = ifelse(str_detect(bodysite_case,"thoracic"),"thoracic",bodysite_case)
  ) %>% 
  #Recalculate the frequency, considering the new bodysite_case variable
  group_by(mod,bodysite_case) %>% 
  summarise(
    Freq = sum(Freq)
  ) %>% 
  #Defining x, y and fill variable
  ggplot(aes(x = bodysite_case, y = Freq, fill = mod))+
  #Making bar plot
  geom_col(position = "dodge", col = "black")+
  #Defining the angle of text in x
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: It's giving me an error: Error in as.data.frame.default(.) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame

Comment: I am using your `dput()` to create `df`

Comment: So how do I alter the code I posted originally so that the groups are combined? It's kind of confusing when you put new lines of code without saying how to incorporate it into the original code